# Your experience with foreign keys

Tags: orm, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

So I am interested in the "use percentage" of FKs in the industry. Do you use FKs in your projects, are there cases when you don't use them? I worked in two companies so far and one of them is quite a leader in the industry and they solve that part of "integrity" in their app layer, so I was interested what is the "ratio" of of DBs with and without FKs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a use percentage for you, but I can tell you it's too low.  Yes, I do use FK constraints where possible, and I design my databases to support their use.  In cases where I didn't or couldn't use them, I frequently ended up having to repair data.  Integrity in the app isn't good enough - the app usually isn't the only user of the database, there's often external conversion/integration apps, and don't forget the DBA who needs to be able to modify data and schema without breaking it.  Even if the app were the only user, I'd rather let the DBMS handle integrity than complicate my code by reinventing that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a link to a horror story of a company that did NOT bother to use foreign keys on (one of) its databases :

[Find GUID in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408023/find-guid-in-database)